# Creating a virtual page without exit

Tags: plugin-development

I would like to create a plugin which is able to display own listing within the body of Wordpress' output. 
As far I understand it's called a virtual page and I found a good [tutorial](https://metabox.io/how-to-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress/) (I think) about how to achieve it. The issue is this tutorial is exiting the entire output. I would rather like to display it within the Wordpress' template.
Is there a proper way to achieve it?

Edit:

So to answer the question, I was basically just playing a bit for now:

```
defined( 'WPINC' ) or die;

add_action( 'init', function () {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'changelog', EP_ALL );
    }
);
add_filter('the_content', function () {
 return "<h1>Hello</h1>";
} );

add_filter( 'the_title', function() {
    return "<p>Nope</p>";
}, 10, 2 );

add_action( 'template_redirect', function () {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( !isset( $wp_query->query_vars[ 'changelog' ] ) ) {
        var_dump( $wp_query->query_vars );
        return;
    }
    return false;
}
);
```

The issue here that it basically needs to rewrite the already loaded post which is a bit a waste of resources imho

Comment: Edited. Sorry for being not precise enough  :)

Comment: What does `var_dump( $wp_query->query_vars )` return?

Comment: Well, simply http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php